# How does Spring know to convert return object to JSON and not XML or any other format?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, http-accept-header

Consider the following:

```
@GetMapping("/accounts/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Account handle() {
    return new Account("1", "sample");
}
```

There is no `Accept` header specified in the request, but still the response is **by default** converted to `JSON` when Spring Boot is used. The `@ResponseBody` annotation, in its [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html), doesn't mention anything about there being a conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
By default, A controller return JSON on spring boot project. But If you want XML format then you can configure this on the pom.xml. For example, you can add this following dependency if you want to return XML data,

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Jackson/Json by default (by finding it in the classpath), but you can configure you're own:

```
@Configuration
public class MixInWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(customHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

See [HttpMessageConverter API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spring-boot applications uses **spring-boot-starter-web** in dependencies of POM.xml. That particular dependency downloads fasterxmls jackson-datatype which is initialized when we use @springbootapplication.

Answer (score 0):

In @requestMapping, You can add variables like Produces or Consumes
Eg:

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE 
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```